# Correct way to store this JSON in python?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to store the JSON object returned from the website https://www.xkcd.com/info.0.json

**What I have tried**

```
url = 'https://www.xkcd.com/info.0.json'
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    response_content = str(response.json())
    print(response_content)
    new_response = response_content.replace("'", '"')
    json_data = json.loads(new_response)
    print(new_response)
    print(json_data)
```

`print(response_content)` returns

```
{
    'link': '',
    'month': '11',
    'num': 1603,
    'title': 'Flashlights',
    'safe_title': 'Flashlights',
    'year': '2015',
    'day': '13',
    'img': 'http: //imgs.xkcd.com/comics/flashlights.png',
    'transcript': '',
    'news': '',
    'alt': "Due to a typo, I initially found a forum for serious Fleshlight enthusiasts, and it turns out their highest-end models are ALSO capable of setting trees on fire. They're impossible to use without severe burns, but some of them swear it's worth it."
}
```

To convert the single quotations in `response_content`, I tried

```
new_response = response_content.replace("'", '"')
```

But the problem arises with the line where `alt` is

```
    .....
    "news": "",
    "alt": "Due to a typo, ...... of setting trees on fire. They"reimpossibletousewithoutsevereburns,
butsomeofthemswearit"s worth it.",
}
```

If there are single quotes inside any of the values, this approach fails.

**Error log :**

```
 File "./main.py", line 55, in download_latest
    json_data = json.loads(new_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 359, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 342 (char 341)
```

Any other approach for loading the JSON inside the script?

**Edit**:

I want to do something like

```
    json_data = json.dumps(response_content)
    print(type(json_data))     ## returns <class 'str'>
    print(json_data['num'])
```

But this returns a `TypeError`

```
File "./main.py", line 53, in download_latest
    print(json_data['num'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Why are you trying to *convert the single quotations in `response_content`* ? Why not just dump it like `import json; json.dumps(response_content)`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by stringifying `response.json()`, changing the quotes, and then re-parsing as JSON?

Comment: I tried `json_data = json.dumps(response_content);  print(type(json_data))` and it says it's a `<class 'str'>`. I wanted to do something like `xkcd_num = json_data['num']` but this returns me an error like `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: @prodicus: Then, `response.json()` returns a `dict` object...

Comment: Why are you converting the *Python structure* returned by `response.json()` to a string? It has *already been decoded*. You don't need to `json.loads()` this again.

Comment: Tip: `response.json()` returns Python object(`dict`), and `response.text` returns raw JSON data as string object. You also can use `json.loads()` or `json.dumps()` on them. And never need `str.replace()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `response.json()` method returns *Python data structures*. You are doing way to much here, you only need:

```
url = 'https://www.xkcd.com/info.0.json'
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    json_data = response.json()
```

That's it.

You are converting the Python data structure to a string, then trying to interpret that string as JSON again. That may look like its working, because the `str()` conversion of a Python container uses Python syntax to produce the result. But Python is not JSON, and your attempts to make it into JSON anyway are unfortunately not very good either. And *not at all needed*.

You can use `json_data` directly, it is a Python dictionary:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://www.xkcd.com/info.0.json'
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> json_data = response.json()
>>> type(json_data)
<type 'dict'>
>>> json_data
{u'img': u'http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/flashlights.png', u'title': u'Flashlights', u'month': u'11', u'num': 1603, u'link': u'', u'year': u'2015', u'news': u'', u'safe_title': u'Flashlights', u'transcript': u'', u'alt': u"Due to a typo, I initially found a forum for serious Fleshlight enthusiasts, and it turns out their highest-end models are ALSO capable of setting trees on fire. They're impossible to use without severe burns, but some of them swear it's worth it.", u'day': u'13'}
>>> print json_data['title']
Flashlights
>>> print json_data['alt']
Due to a typo, I initially found a forum for serious Fleshlight enthusiasts, and it turns out their highest-end models are ALSO capable of setting trees on fire. They're impossible to use without severe burns, but some of them swear it's worth it.
```

Comment: I didn't know that `response.json()` returned a `dict` object. Good explanation @Martijin :)

Comment: @prodicus: it returns the decoded JSON structure. Most APIs use JSON objects, so the result will usually be a dict, but a JSON array would be possible too (giving you a list), or any of the JSON primitives (string, integer, floating point number, boolean, null).

Comment: @prodicus: in this case it is a dictionary, because that's what is in the JSON response.

Answer (score 2):

`response.json()` already returns a python dictionary:

```
import requests
import json
url = 'https://www.xkcd.com/info.0.json'
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    response_content = response.json()
    print response_content
```

There is no need to convert to and from strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json, requests

r = requests.get('https://www.xkcd.com/info.0.json')
responseJSON = None
if r.status_code == 200:
    responseJSON = json.loads(r.content)

print responseJSON  # you can access values like responseJSON['img']
```

Since here, you are sure of a `JSON` response, you might as well do

```
responseJSON = r.json()
```

**Note**: You must still do error handling.

Comment: `>>> responseJSON == r.json()`:    
`True`

Comment: @KevinGuan even better! I will add that alternate approach